# Message: not enough computer space for iphone backup

Tags: backup, iphone

My iPhone 4s won't backup. I receive the message:

> not enough space on computer.

There is plenty of space on my mac, 220 gigabytes free.

Comment: Do you have more than one drive or partition?  By default, the backups go to the boot volume, so you could encounter this even if there is space elsewhere on the system.  Also check permissions since an unwritable folder could have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. It finally came down to backup software - in my case CrashPlan. I "slept" the backup for a few hours, restarted the backup, and it completed successfully. It seemed like CrashPlan would lock the file after the iTunes finished writing the file out right as it was renaming it from a temporary name to the permanent name.